# Jquery scrolling effect for 5 contionuous section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Does any one have the code for the below. A single page has 5 `div`s and each `div` has `overflow-y scrollbar`. When I am scrolling from the top of the first `div`, when the first `div` ends, the next `div`'s scroll needs to start until end of the same `div`. The third `div start` scrolling when second `div` ends. As like above the same thing need to done for scrolling upwards, using Jquery. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and any JS you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything yet? I ran into a similar problem a while ago and made a simple solution, this might help you get things started.

```
$('div').scroll(function(){

    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        /*if the div's scrollTop plus its height equals to 
        its scrollHeight, you reached the bottom of div.
        Move to the next div by animating the body scrollTop 
        with the div's offset top
        */
        var next = $(this).next().offset().top;
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:next});

    }else if($(this).scrollTop() == 0){
        /*if the div's scrolltop equals 0,
         you reached the top
        move to the previous div sibling
        */
        var prev = $(this).prev().offset().top;
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:prev});        
    }
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6r6j/).